# How can I play audio on Hostinger?

Tags: html, css, audio

The audio tag isn't working in Hostinger. I am hosting my website there but there is no music.

[www.greenlight-festival.com](http://www.greenlight-festival.com)

For example:

```
<audio id="Da">
        <source src="../Music/Da.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controlsList="nodownload" >
    </audio>
```

Can someone pls help me?

I tried to shorten the direction and moved the Music folder directly to the public folder, it isn't helping either. I have emailed hosting themselves but they gave me the impression that they don't know much about their own server.

Comment: Your `id="UrBoy"` and `id="Da"` cards work, but the `id="Millie"` card is throwing a 404 error for the file. The other two are set up as `src="../Music/<title>.mp3"` but you have the Millie card set up as `src="public_html/Music/Milli.mp3"` Change the Milli card URL to match the others, that's where your file is actually located. https://www.greenlight-festival.com/Music/Milli.mp3

Comment: Hi, I have changed the source code to .../Music/Milli.mp3 but I am still not hearing any sound. None of them give any sound while if I try the live server on Pycharm, they do play sound.

Comment: Looks like they're working on your site now with the links having been corrected